# Silverlight 5 - Downloading a zip File from WebService asmx

Tags: c#, silverlight, download, asmx

I try to set up a silverlight application (OOB) with a webservice.
On the server i have stored .zip - Files and i want the Silverlight-client to download these files through a webservice using the SaveFileDialog.

How does the code looks like

a) in the webservice.asmx.cs

```
[WebMethod]
public downloadZip()
{
  String knownPath = "C:\\test.zip";
  //Code?
}
```

b) in the Silverlight Client using C#

```
public void getZipFiles()
{
  TestService.WebServiceSoapClient service = new TestService.WebServiceSoapClient();
  //Code?
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this to send binary format using web service

This article show you how to build a Web service and a Web service client to send and receive binary documents by using Microsoft ASP.NET and Microsoft Visual C# .NET.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/318425

Comment: Thanks! The link was really helpful. I tried it, but it doesnt work. I get an error "Implicit conversion from type void to string is not possible" or void to int (for each method in the webservice).

Comment: The code provided in above link is working fine. One of mine friends use the link to write the same logic. The error you got is just conversion programming error, resolved that and move forward.

Comment: Thanks a lot - The problem was that i didnt know the difference between synchron and asynchron webservice. Now everything works fine. Have a nice day!

Comment: That's Good!! Have a nice day too!